# Manufacturer Or Hardware Developer Can't Provide Driver For HDMI?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi

I'm in a interesting predicament, a few years back my hard drive in my laptop up and quit on me, so I had to replace it and do a clean install of windows. I thought I had installed all the drivers, I thought wrong.

It seems I missed the HDMI audio driver for my machine, and much to my chagrin, it seems neither the manufacturer of the laptop (samsung) or the manufacturers of the graphics hardware (Nvidia and Intel, it's a optimus machine,) seem to be able to provide the drivers for the HDMI audio.

The machine is a Samsung NP-QX410-S02CA and the hardware ID of the part in question is HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2804&SUBSYS_80860101&REV_1000, which when doing a quick search is just turning of spam sites, not helpful at all. I assume the driver in question is a intel driver but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Did you try downloading the sound driver from [here](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/NP-QX410-S02CA).

Comment: If I may pass along a "best practice" piece of advice for future reference:  at least one a year, I perform an extra backup procedure for every machine on my home network.  I copy the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder to an external USB drive and/or DVD-R disc.  As a result, if the hard drive hosting the operating system partition should fail or I need to perform a full wipe-and-reload for any reason, I have all of the device drivers for that machine readily available.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Dell website and look for the Windows 7 drivers for the Dell Optiplex 330 computer.

It uses that same chipset and has the correct Intel HD Audio bus-driver.

Driver should work on your computer too and the Dell site won't try to push spam on you.

P.S. For a generic Intel chipset motherboard the Optiplex 330 is a fairly standard machine. The drivers for it are quite generic and work on a large range of other computers.